# detecting a long press and press

Tags: java, android

in this function，I want to achieve “if is long press,return flag=true,else open tile”.`

```
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int x=(int)event.getX();
        int y=(int)event.getY();
        long DownTime = event.getDownTime();
        long UpTime = event.getEventTime();
        long longPresstouch = UpTime - DownTime;
        int idxX=(x-mine.x)/mine.tileWidth;
        int idxY=(y-mine.y)/mine.tileWidth;
        if(longPresstouch > longTouchTime)
        {
            if(x>=mine.x&&y>=mine.y&&x<=(mine.mapWidth+mine.x)&&y<=(mine.y+mine.mapHeight)) {
                mine.setflag(new Mine.Point(idxX, idxY), true);
                invalidate();
            }
        }
        else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            if(x>=mine.x&&y>=mine.y&&x<=(mine.mapWidth+mine.x)&&y<=(mine.y+mine.mapHeight))  //in tile or out tile
            {
                mine.open(new Mine.Point(idxX,idxY),isFirst);
                isFirst=false;

                if(mine.tile[idxY][idxX].value==-1)
                {
                    mine.isDrawAllMine=true;
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setMessage("GameOver,你踩到地雷啦！")
                            .setPositiveButton("再来一局", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    mine.init();
                                    isFalse=true;
                                    isFirst=true;
                                    invalidate();
                                }
                            })
                            .setNegativeButton("退出游戏", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    System.exit(0);
                                }
                            })
                            .create()
                            .show();
                }
                if(isFalse)
                {
                    isFalse=false;
                    invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                logic();
                invalidate();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

`

but It is not working when I long press the tile. It is executing “open tile”.

[image]
[image]

How to correct the function? I am a beginner. Maybe this is a very simple question，but this has already perplexed me for a long time.

Comment: Provide your other code as Text and Give more detail like is it with RecyclerView or what?Never post your code as image.

Answer (score 0):

Every Android components that extend `android.view.View` will have these 2 methods.

1. `View.setOnClickListener()` If you do a click.
2. `View.setOnLongClickListener()` If you do long click. Make sure it's `View.isLongClickable()` returns true, or set it by calling `View.setLongClickable(true)`.

Comment: This won't help give options for individual cells within the canvas of the question

Answer (score 0):

Because you're reacting to the down and showing the dialog.  Since you're reacting to the down event immediately, you never wait to see if its a long press.  This is why touch events in android generally happen on the up event-  so you can figure out if the touch is going to be a press, long press, gesture, etc.

Also, as another poster said, click and long clock are built in events.  No reason to write an onTouchEvent unless you want to capture more complex behavior.

Comment: Looks like the OP is writing minesweeper without a view for each cell

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the time difference between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP. If time difference is greater than 1000 ms return true else open the tile.